# email response that what time email is opened and received

Tags: java, email

How I can track an email?

I'm using java on the server side for sending emails. I want to track whether it is delivered, opened, etc. How I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, e-mail isn't that simple.

You can use some techniques to get a better understanding of when an e-mail is opened, for instance, but it's not guaranteed.

One usual approach is to include an image, for instance (a beacon), that makes a request to your server when it's loaded.

Of course, some mail clients will ask the user if he allows the loading of external content. If he says no, there's nothing you can do.

Like posted in a comment, you can look up more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_tracking and by googling the subject, a lot has been written about it.